# Ionic extra scrollable area while using ion-slide-box

Tags: ionic-framework, ion-slide-box

I am using ion-slide-box having multiple slides. One slide has too large content but others have less content. Issue is that all the slides are taking the same height as that of the slide with the largest height and that's why creating an extra scrollable area in other slides. 
All slides should take height according to the content, please help me to figure out this problem.

[image]

Comment: http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/tLnFs - codepen link, this will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ion-slide-box always takes the height of longest slide. I explicitly defined the height of each slide and that works for me so far.